# Normal convergence of a sequence of holomorphic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

**Definition of normal convergence:** Let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions defined on some space $X$. We say that the series $\sum_{n\ge 1} f_n$ converges normally on $X$ if the series $\sum_{n\ge 1} \sup_X \lvert f_n \rvert$ is convergent.

---

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions on a domain $\Omega$ of $\mathbb C$. Assume that the series $\sum_{n\ge 1} f_n$ converges normally on all compact subsets of $\Omega$ and let's denote the infinite sum $\sum_{n\ge 1} f_n$ by $f$. Now there is a conclusion saying that the series $\sum_{n\ge 1} (f_n)^\prime$ converges normally on all compact subsets of $\Omega$ to $f^\prime$.

I know there is a fact that if $\sum_{n\ge 1} f_n$ converges *uniformly* to $f$, then $\sum_{n\ge 1} (f_n)^\prime$ converges *uniformly* to $f^\prime$. The proof of this fact basically uses the Cauchy integral formula and the passage under integral sign of uniform convergence.

But for the case of normal convergence, I am quite confused. We only know $\sum_{n\ge 1} \sup \lvert f_n \rvert=\sup \lvert f\rvert$ and we have to use it to prove that $\sum_{n\ge 1} \sup \lvert (f_n)^\prime \rvert=\sup \lvert f^\prime \rvert$, which implies that we need to interchange the operations of differentiation and taking supremum. This implication seems wrong to me.

Can anyone offer me a proof or tell me that this conclusion is wrong? Thanks for help.

---

**Edit:** [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265032/normal-convergence) is a analogue of my question but it is in the real space.

Comment: Hint: let $\beta \subset B$ be open balls contained in $\Omega$ such that $B \supset \overline{\beta}$ and $\overline{B} \subset \Omega$. By the Cauchy formula, for any holomorphic $f$ on $\Omega$, $\|f’\|_{\infty,\beta} \leq C_{\beta,B} \|f\|_{\infty,B}$. Can you use this to solve your issue?

Comment: @Mindlack Thanks for the hint, but I still can't figure it out. The inequality is only one-side and what I can get is merely something like $\sum ||(f_n)^\prime ||_{\infty,\beta} \le C_{\beta,B} ||f||_{\infty,B}$, which seems irrelevant to $||f^\prime||_\infty$. Can you provide me with some more details. I will be so grateful.

Comment: No, that’s not what you get. You get $\sum{\|(f_n)’\|_{\infty,\beta}} \leq C_{\beta,B}\sum{\|f_n\|_{\infty,B}} < \infty$ so the series of $f’_n$ converges locally normally so it converges normally on all compacts.

Comment: @Mindlack You are right. From that we can prove that the sequence is normally convergent. But how can we show that this limit is exactly $f^\prime$ itself? Thanks for further comments in advance.

Comment: There is no specific notion of “converging normally to $f’$”. There is a notion of “converging normally” and a notion of “converging to $f’$” (eg uniformly). We’ve settled the former, and the second follows from the fact that normal convergence implies uniform convergence, and the fact that you’ve cited in the second paragraph of the post.

Comment: @Mindlack Thanks! I understand now.